# How can I disable AWS X-Ray when running with Lambda-local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda

https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local

Every time I start my lambda with this tool I get:

```
Error: Missing AWS Lambda trace data for X-Ray. Ensure Active Tracing is enabled and no subsegments are created outside the function handler.
    at Object.contextMissingLogError [as contextMissing] (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/foo/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/context_utils.js:22:27)
    at Segment.resolveLambdaTraceData (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/fields-dp/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/env/aws_lambda.js:86:49)
    at Object.getSegment (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/fields-dp/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/context_utils.js:92:25)
    at Object.resolveSegment (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/fields-dp/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/context_utils.js:71:25)
    at captureOutgoingHTTPs (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/fields-dp/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/patchers/http_p.js:84:37)
```

It's just an annoyance / visual noise and I think it's breaking `pino-pretty`. I see no value to running X-Ray while running a lambda locally. I tried setting `export AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED=false` and `unset AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED`, neither one worked. The AWS XRay code is coming in from an internal library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING=IGNORE_ERROR` took care of it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration-envvars